# Refreshing a Specific Section of a Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I currently have a modal that deletes an item from my list of data. After selecting delete, I want to refresh the web page. At this point, it is refreshing the entire page and re-directing me to the `Searches` tab. I want to refresh just the `Lists` tab. How can I do this?

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="row zero-margin">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div id="tabstrip">
                <ul id="tab-strip-options">
                    <li id="listItem1" class="k-state-active">
                        Searches
                    </li>
                    <li id="listItem2">
                        Lists
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="saved-search-content">
                    <div id="gridSearch"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="saved-list-content">
                    <div id="gridList"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**My JavaScript Function:**

```
function deleteItemsFromList(data) {
    if(data.IsSuccess) {
        window.location.reload();
        CloseModal("deleteSearchListModal");
        showSuccessMessage('List was successfully deleted!');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! You will need some ajax here. Hey, how you are populating this list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution for server side data store:**

The easiest solution for partial update on your web page is to use AJAX requests. You must load list content from web source, when you update it.

```
$( "#gridList" ).load( "ajax/getListContent" );
```

Of course your `ajax/getListContent` must generate proper HTML substructure (without html, body tags) like:

```
<div>...</div>
```

Generally create a data source on address `ajax/getListContent` which return you your data structured in HTML, then in your code you can do like this:

```
function deleteItemsFromList(data) {
    if(data.IsSuccess) {
        $( "#gridList" ).load( "ajax/getListContent", function() {
           CloseModal("deleteSearchListModal");
           showSuccessMessage('List was successfully deleted!');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay @suvroc, your idea makes sense but not really sure how to implement this. Could you please expand?

Comment: What is your backend? From what source you take data to page?

Comment: Where does `ajax/getListContent` come from?

Comment: It is your other page generated on your server filled by data. For example you get data from database and generate html table for them

Comment: So I'm getting closer, but here is the issue I run into now. If I have 11 items, 10 on the first page and 1 on the second. When I delete the 11th item on the second page my page count says: `2 of 1` even when there is no content left on page 2. Why doesn't the `ajax` update that as well?

Comment: Your ajax can have parameters (number of items, page) and as a result return (current page, all pages count, data). Page change can be made server side, because there you have that kind of knowledge

Answer (score 1):

I completely ignore if you are using some kind of plugin, but if you want to refresh just part of the whole HTML document, you have to use AJAX and remove the `window.location.reload()` from your script. Something like this:

```
function deleteItemsFromList(data) {
    if(data.IsSuccess) {
        $.ajax(/*params here*/).done(function(data){
            //refresh just the #gridList part
            CloseModal("deleteSearchListModal");
            showSuccessMessage('List was successfully deleted!');
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe this is not the correct order, but the important thing is AJAX :)

Comment: Hey @Vithozor, thanks for your reply. What type of params would I want to insert into the `ajax` and how do I call the refresh on `#gridList`

Comment: You can find how to use jQuery's Ajax here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

I'm not sure of the best way for you, but I would do:
1. AJAX to server
2. Delete whatever I need to delete
3. Return an object with fresh information from server
4. Handle the response in the `done()` part

Comment: So I'm getting closer, but here is the issue I run into now. If I have 11 items, 10 on the first page and 1 on the second. When I delete the 11th item on the second page my page count says: `2 of 1` even when there is no content left on page 2. Why doesn't the `ajax` update that as well?